# Trouble inserting dates into Oracle 11g Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm getting a missing comma error message which I can't seem to fix. My code is below.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers
(
C_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DOB date
Age int,
FirstName varchar(255),
LastName varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
MemberSince int
);

INSERT 
INTO
   Customers

VALUES
  (C_Id.nextval,'TO_DATE( '02-DEC-1977', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )',37,'Joseph','Smith','Minneapolis',2004);
```

Comment: Not the reason for your error, but: it's good coding style to list the columns of the table you insert into: `insert into customers (c_id, dob, age, firstname, lastname, city, membersince) values (....)`

Comment: Not sure why you unaccepted my answer, apart from the edit you made, adding a comma is still not enough to make this work on Oracle 11g. Maybe an explanation if there's valuable information for others who'd have this issue that made you change your mind?

Comment: Purely an accident. I have to get reputation points as a class assignment so up vote if you would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks problematic to me:

```
'TO_DATE( '02-DEC-1977', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )'
```

Try unquoting the TO_DATE like this:

```
TO_DATE( '02-DEC-1977', 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
```

You might also need to create the sequence first:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE C_Id
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
 CACHE 20;

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
  C_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  DOB date,
  Age int,
  FirstName varchar(255),
  LastName varchar(255),
  City varchar(255),
  MemberSince int
);

INSERT 
INTO
  Customers
VALUES
  (C_Id.nextval,TO_DATE( '02-DEC-1977', 'DD-MON-YYYY' ),37,'Joseph','Smith','Minneapolis',2004);
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you missed the coma after **DOB date** it should be **DOB date,** in CREATE TABLE statement

Comment: The missing comma was a mistake made in the edit of the question, and it still won't work unless you remove the quotes around TO_DATE and create the sequence. But yes, given the edit, you also need to add the comma after date.